# Issues when seeing my webpage in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have finally finished my webpage. it works flawlessly in Google Chrome. However, I decided to check how it would be seen on Firefox, and it's completely messed up [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4RR9.png). You can see it live at http://164.132.103.92/ (if you use chrome it will be seen ok, if you use firefox you will see it messed up.

I'm using bootstrap. This is my index code: (scripts omitted)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="SemiColonWeb" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

        <!-- Stylesheets
        ============================================= -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-icons.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Document Title
        ============================================= -->
        <title>Buscador de imagenes</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a:hover {
                color: white;
            }
            .button.button-border:hover {
                background-color: white;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                color: grey !important;
            }
            .image-controlled {
                position: relative; 
                background-size: contain;
            }
            #autor{
                font-weight: bold !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="stretched">
        <!-- Document Wrapper
        ============================================= -->
        <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <!-- Header
            ============================================= -->
            <header id="header" class="full-header">
                <div id="header-wrap">
                    <section id="page-title">
                        <div class="container clearfix">
                            <div  style="width:690px;">
                                <h2 style="display: inline; font-size: 180%">LA PINTURA DEL SIGLO XIX EN EL MUNDO OCCIDENTAL
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                ARCHIVO DE IMÁGENES</h2><h1 class="pull-right" style="display: inline; font-weight:normal;"><strong>AI </strong>XIX</h1>
                            </div>
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <li><a href="#">Presentación</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sobre el autor</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </section>
            </header><!-- #header end -->
            <!-- Content
            ============================================= -->

                <?php
                include("funciones.php");
                $link=conectar();
                $link->set_charset("utf8");
                $random = mt_rand(1, 75);
                ?>
            <!--<div class="image-controlled">

            <img src="imagenespresentacion/<?php echo $random; ?>.jpg";  id="full-screen-background-image" >
            <img src="imagenespresentacion/<?php echo $random; ?>.jpg"; width: cover;>

                    <section id="content" style="background-image: url(&quot;imagenespresentacion/<?php echo $random; ?>&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">


            -->
            <section id="content" style="background-image: url(&quot;imagenespresentacion/<?php echo $random; ?>&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">


            <!--    <div class="section parallax dark notopmargin noborder" style="padding: 80px 0px; background-image: url(&quot;imagesEj/parallax/home/5.jpg&quot;); background-position: 50% -92.4px;" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4">
                -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="section parallax white col-md-2" style="width: 132px; padding-top: 100px; padding-right: 0px; margin-right: 0; left:100;">
                            <p>

                                <label style="color: white;" for="pais">Paises</label><br>
                                <select name="pais" id='pais' size="10" onchange='cargarSelect2(this.value);'>
                                    <option value='0'>Selecciona un pais</option>
                                    <?php 
                                        $sql="SELECT * FROM pais";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                                        $i=1;
                                        $arrayAutoresT= array();
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 
                                            $idP=$row[0];
                                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$row[1].'</option>'; 
                                            $i++;
                                            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM autor WHERE ID_Pais='$idP' Order by nombre ASC";
                                            $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1);
                                            //recorremos el pais sacando autores
                                            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){ 
                                                $temp=array("idPais" => $idP, "nAutor" => $row1[1], "idAutor" => $row1[0]);
                                                $arrayAutoresT[]=$temp;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?> 
                                </select>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="section parallax white col-md-2" style="width: 333px; padding-top: 100px; padding-left: 0px; background-position: 50% -92.4px;" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4">
                            <p>
                                <label style="color: white;" for="autor">Autores</label><br>
                                <select name="autor" id='autor' size="10" onchange='seleccinado_select2();' disabled>
                                    <option value='0'>Selecciona un autor</option>
                                </select>
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix center col-md-8" style="padding-left: 10px; width: 700px;">
                            <div class="emphasis-title" >
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                                <!--<h2>Buscador de autores</h2>-->
                                <Form Name ="form" Method ="POST" ACTION = "imagen.php">
                                    <p class="lead topmargin-sm" style="color: white;">Introduce el ID o el nombre del autor que deseas buscar</p>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-line-search"></i></div>
                                        <input id="icons-filter" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="ID o nombre del autor a buscar" type="text" name="id">
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="comparador_index.php" style="color">Comparar dos autores</a>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <INPUT class="button button-xlarge button-border button-rounded tright" style="margin-top: 2%; color:white; border-color:white;" TYPE = "Submit" Name = "enviar" VALUE ="Buscar">
                                    </INPUT>

                                </Form>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
            <!--</img>
            </div>-->


            <!-- Footer
            ============================================= -->
            <footer id="footer" class="white">
                <!-- Copyrights
                ============================================= -->
                <div id="copyrights">
                    <div class="container clearfix">
                        Copyrights &copy; 2016 Todos los derechos reservados<br>
                        <div class="copyright-links"><a href="#">Aviso legal</a> / <a href="#">Política de privacidad</a></div>
                    </div>

                    </div>

                </div><!-- #copyrights end -->

            </footer><!-- #footer end -->

        </div><!-- #wrapper end -->

        <!-- Go To Top
        ============================================= -->
        <div id="gotoTop" class="icon-angle-up"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what "messed up" means, clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your id ="content" has a css style of "Overflow"="hidden" in style.css page.. remove that and it works fine

Comment: Sorry, I put up a link with a screenshot, due to that stack overflow doesn't allow to put the image directly.

Comment: Karthik that worked! Now the background is correctly placed, however, now the content scrolls a bit with the user until it reaches the footer. That may be a problem of the position property?

Comment: looks like.. try to play around with it using the developer tool in-bult within chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add:

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
```

To your background image css propriety.